# Find unused TWIG layouts in a Symfony project

Tags: symfony, twig

### tl;dr

Is there in the Symfony ecosystem an existing tool specifically meant to find unused Twig layouts, i.e. all layout files which are not included / embedded in other layouts nor rendered by any controller in the project?

### Details

After a huge frontend refactoring task on a big project, it may take a while and/or some trial-and-error sessions to find which layout files are not used anymore.

I was wondering if there is an existing tool / command that shows a list of (possibly) unused layout files. Of course layout names can be dynamically created so the list would still need to be carefully checked, but still it seems like that could save some time.

Thank you in advance for any answer.

Comment: why not just grep code to see if it uses template name? could build bash script with array of twig filenames, grep code for that and see results

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs thank you for your suggestion. Of course I can do that, but my question was very specific: *is there an existing tool to do that*, not *how can I find unused twig layouts*. If there is not, I will definitely rely on some bash scripting or similar solution.

Comment: In that case not to my knowledge :) (though I haven't been Symfony-ing long)

Comment: That would be a feature i am also very interested in. I think there are dozens of templates i am not sure i am using it anymore. But being to shy to remove it in case its still used somewhere ...

Comment: No tool AFAIK. Twig doesn't know what templates you have anyway, until you use them. How about [custom data collector](http://symfony.com/doc/current/profiler/data_collector.html) and log used twig templates? You can check out how `TwigDataCollector` works and develop your own. Then compare this list with the list of your templates (simple `find . -name '*.html.twig'` will do)

Comment: This question seems off-topic. If you asked _how can I find unused twig layouts_ then your question was probably more suitable for SO but currently you're looking for a tool.

Comment: @emix thank you for your suggestion. Your comment is a bit closer to what I was looking for, i.e. something within the Symfony ecosystem rather than raw bash scripting. Since it looks like there is no existing tool, I will probably look into that.

Comment: @Nima you may be right, though my question was more about an existing Symfony command or Twig API to do just that. It was more about looking for an undocumented feature than a generic request for a tool. But your comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the docs (https://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html) the answer is **no** there is no tool/feature to find unused templates in symfony even if there may be other methods to find them.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: No answer here, just your assumption.

Comment: There is nothing contrary in the docs. When it's an valid answer in your opinion?

Comment: But someone outside the symfony project could have made a 3rd party tool which is not in it?

Comment: If your answer is based on docs then it would be nice to add a link to the part of docs that you're referring to.

Comment: But it is not a link to a specific part of docs which give information supporting your answer, it is a link to first page of Symfony documentation.

Comment: I don't understand. How to link to an information which is not existing? Go to the site, search for the specific information and you'll not find anything about the issue in this Question. What is the problem?

Comment: You just pointed out the problem, the problem is _referring to some information that does not exist_. This answer is not actually *based* on documentation. If docs explicitly stated that this is not possible for a specific reason, then we could link to that information to support the *no* answer given here. I agree with emix and DarkBee, someone outside Symfony project could have made a tool that we're not aware of, we can't assume the other way.

Comment: Ok if the context is "anywhere outside" i agree with your argumentation because i don't know every source for symfony tools. If the context is "official symfony" i don't. That would be just like if you say "This car can fly because the manual isn't explicit negating this statement"

Comment: Sorry people, I did not mean to create confusion. The answer from @JimPanse is technically correct. It is not his fault if it does not add much value. In the spirit of SO, the only way to add more value would be if: a) such a tool existed or b) someone would explain at length and based on experience why such a tool does not exists (e.g. because of unexpected technical issues or because of simpler alternatives). Thank you all for your time.

Comment: I'm agree with this... After all, the question is a boolean question, is there something, Yes or No... Difficult to explain why there is nothing....

Answer (score 3):

In my quest, I finally made a script to find twig templates not referenced in templates/ or src/ files:

```
APP_PATH=./$1
TWIG_PATH=${APP_PATH}/templates

# find all files in TWIG_PATH, remove TWIG_PATH from the string
for i in $( find $TWIG_PATH  -type f -not -path '*/\.*' -exec echo {}  \; | cut -b $((${#TWIG_PATH}+2))-  ); do
    # search for the path in src and templates
    if ! grep "$i" ${APP_PATH}/src ${APP_PATH}/templates -r -hc -m1 | grep -qv 0 
    then 
        echo $i;
    fi
done
```